# This works in Junit but it shouldn't ..can someone tell me how to correct it and why it works?

Tags: java, junit

Test class:

```
public class TestClass extends TestCase
{
    private static final String TEXT_MESSAGE_VALUE = "<test>Me</test>";
    private static final String JMS_MESSAGE_ID = "This is the correlation id.";
    private Serializable xmlSerializable;


    @Test
    public void testCreateMessage() throws Exception
    {
        Session mockSession = createMock(Session.class);
        TextMessage mockTextMessage = createMock(TextMessage.class);
        expect(mockSession.createTextMessage(TEXT_MESSAGE_VALUE)).andReturn(mockTextMessage);
        mockTextMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(JMS_MESSAGE_ID);
        replay(mockSession, mockTextMessage);
        test.createMessage(mockSession);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; it's not bad practice to have sanity checks on method arguments...

Comment: @phoenix: as per your code you want to compare two xml string through assertion, please correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: @phoenix: i have added one solution for comparing two DomElement hope it will work for your need if you are using Dom4j, please let me know if will fulfill your need.

Comment: You're using the Java `assert` keyword in places rather than JUnit's assertions; are you running with assertions enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the class in question it's impossible to know whether or not it's sensible for `serializedMsg` to be null. If the class doesn't initialize it as part of its construction, and there are no processes running that interact with the class, I'd expect it to stay null.

That there's JMS involved to me implies there are other factors in play, however, so without knowing more about the context the test is running in, tough to say for sure.

Unrelated, but IMO an `IllegalArgumentException` makes no sense here, because it's not being thrown against an illegal argument. Maybe an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @Phoenix IMO there's still not enough information. Are you saying the test passes, or not?

Comment: @Phoenix Then there's something in your test runner, configuration, etc that uses that class to receive JMS messages, or *something* among those lines. As I said originally, without more information, we won't be able to tell you why it passes.

Answer (score 0):

using dom4j i have done it like that way in past for comparing two domElement
>

```
public static boolean compare(Element element1, Element element2){
        if(element1 == null || element2 == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            NodeComparator nc = new NodeComparator();
            return (nc.compare(element1, element2) == 0);
        }
    }
```

i think if you are using DOM4j then it will work for you,